# Equivalent of python's encode('utf8') in golang

Tags: python, go, utf-8, language-comparisons

How can I convert a string in Golang to UTF-8 in the same way as one would use `str.encode('utf8')` in Python? (I am trying to translate some code from Python to Golang; the str comes from user input, and the encoding is used to calculate a hash)

As far as I understand, the Python code converts unicode text into a string. The string is a collection of UTF-8 bytes. This sounds similar to strings in Go. So is this encoding already done for me when I store some text as a Go string?

Should I walk over the string and try `utf8.EncodeRune` in go? I'm really confused.

Comment: strings in Go are assumed to be utf8 encoded. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I am trying to bcrypt a password that a user enters. The python code does an str.encode('utf8') before bcrypting it. I was wondering how do I do the equivalent in Go, but I guess it's "already handled"?

Comment: Read https://blog.golang.org/strings carefully.

Answer (score 19):

In Python, `str.encode('utf8')` converts a string to bytes. In Go, strings are utf-8 encoded already, if you need bytes, you can do: `[]byte(str)`.

Answer (score 0):

Since go has already encoded string, still for sake of displaying it in python-like text.

```
fmt.Printf("%q\n", "string");
```